# Posting data from MVC to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am learning `MVC` with `WEB API` I have `Controller` in MVC which make calls to Web Api for further actions. I have successfully retrieve the data from API to controller, but I am unable to post data from Controller to API.
In the DAL section, where should I put my values against parameters. My database is Oracle

How do I get data there in API, As I am still learning if any improvement in this code required, your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**My MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.DeviceType device)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response; 
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            response = httpClient.PostAsync(ApiUrl + "DeviceTypeApi/AddDeviceType", device, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return View("GetAllDeviceTypes");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**API Controller**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AddDeviceType")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddDeviceType()
{
    objDeviceBL = new DeviceBL();
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        var deviceResponse = objDeviceBL.AddDeviceType(); //this will further move it to business logic
        if (deviceResponse != null)
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse<List<Models.DeviceType>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, deviceResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
    return response;
}
```

**BL**

```
internal new List<Models.DeviceType> AddDeviceType()
{
    return base.AddDeviceType();
}
```

**Core**

```
protected List<DeviceType> AddDeviceType()
{
    List<DeviceType> objDeviceTypes = null;
    try
    {
        objDeviceTypes = new DeviceDAL().AddDeviceType();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }

    return objDeviceTypes;
}
```

**DAL**

```
public List<DeviceType> AddDeviceType()
{
    List<DeviceType> objDeviceTypes = new List<DeviceType>();
    using (cmd = new OracleCommand("SP_DMS_DEVICE_TYPE_INSERT", con))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_typename", OracleType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_createdby", OracleType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_createdon", OracleType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_updatedby", OracleType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_updatedon", OracleType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            con.Open();
            adap = new OracleDataAdapter();
            adap.InsertCommand = cmd;                    
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            con.Close();
        }
        return objDeviceTypes;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change Your api controller action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AddDeviceType")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddDeviceType(Models.DeviceType device)
{
    //Here You can manipulate with device object
}
```

ASP will map device object from request json to c# object for You.